# PL/SQL - Delete current record in FOR IN LOOP

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-delete, for-in-loop

I am trying to figure out how to delete a record using the FOR .. IN .. LOOP

```
FOR REC IN (SELECT * FROM WORKLIST) LOOP
  GET_DATA(REC);
  --DELETE REC FROM WORKLIST
END LOOP;
```

The GET_DATA procedure explodes every row to multiple ones so the current one becomes obsolete. I am trying to delete just the current record. Not sure if this is possible using the REC object in this case.

Sadly, WORKLIST does not have any keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [current of](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_adv_plsql_for_update_where_current.htm) on cursor :

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT * from worklist FOR UPDATE <any column name>; 
BEGIN 
      open c1; 
      loop 
          fetch c1 into crow; 
          exit when c1%notfound;  
          DELETE FROM worklist WHERE CURRENT OF c1; 
      end loop;        
      COMMIT; 
      close c1; 
END;
```

Comment: `For Update` is generally discourged. This can cause deadlocks. Read more here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4530093713805

Comment: @XING - I think you misunderstood Tom Kyte's response. FOR UPDATE allows us to implement a pessimistic locking strategy which *avoids* deadlocks.

Comment: @APC. In the earlier section it also showed that `FOR UPDATE` caused deadlocks. I was referring correct. Please refer the whole article

Comment: @XING - that's `deadlock detected`, which causes the second attempted transaction to fail. That's what we want to happen. Without FOR UPDATE both sessions  would fail.

Comment: @APC. That's what i said. `FOR UPDATE` can lead to deadlocks. Where did you find me worng here. And thats why he referred an example with Autonomus transaction.

Comment: @XING - I don't think Tom Kyte discourages FOR UPDATE. I think he advocates the proper use of FOR UPDATE.

Comment: @APC. Why do you think in the tom's example that without `FOR UPDATE` both session will fail. It's only showing that since the first transaction was incomplete(neither commited nor rollbacked),the second caused the error. And this is the reason its discouraged.

Comment: @xing - well what would you want the second session to do?

Comment: @APC. Certainly `FOR UDPATE` will not make atleast `BOTH` the sessions fail. It would cause the seoncf to wait till the first one completes.

Answer (score 2):

If WORKLIST has a primary key, just use it:

```
DELETE FROM WORKLIST WHERE <PK> = REC.<PK>
```

If no primary key I would try:

```
DECLARE
  vTmp schema.worklist%rowtype;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT rowid, w.* FROM WORKLIST w) LOOP
    vTmp := null;
    vTmp.col1 := rec.col1;
    vTmp.col2 := rec.col2;
    -- And so on ...
    GET_DATE(vTmp);
    DELETE FROM WORKLIST WHERE rowid = rec.rowid;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Sadly, WORKLIST does not have any keys.

Comment: Oh I like that, only thing now I get an error on the GET_DATA(REC) line. 
Error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_DATA'. The definition of that procedure is the following: PROCEDURE GET_DATA(P_REC WWMT_WORKLIST%ROWTYPE) IS ... Is there a way to include ROWID in that ROWTYPE?

Comment: I see two options: 1) Declare a cursor with the rowid in a wider scope and use the rowtype of such cursor in both procedures. 2) Use a WORKLIST%ROWTYPE variable and copy all the column values -except rowid- from the current record to the variable. So you will pass the variable to the procedure.

Comment: How would I go about doing option 2? I'm not familiar with that.